# Update Athena Table using AWS Data Wrangler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-data-wrangler

I started using `AWS Data Wrangler` and `Athena`, to upload my data files onto S3, and being able to query them, respectively. My question is about the procedure to "safely" update the data in the table.

Here is what I did:

1. I used the AWS Data Wrangler,

   ```
   wr.s3.to_parquet(
   df=my_df,
   path='s3://temp',
   dataset=True,
   partition_cols = ['date'],
   concurrent_partitioning = True,
   mode = append
   )
   ```

   to export my `DataFrame` to S3 -as `parquet` files.
2. I used AWS Glue to crawl my data files in S3, and create `Table A`.
3. Via Athena, I can query my data in `Table A`.

Now I would like to **update** my data in table A. My questions are:

1. (insert new rows):
   If I follow what I did above, and change the mode to "overwrite", then all my data in S3 is removed (expected, not desirable!), and the new data files is written onto S3. Thus, the Glue catalogue crawl results in NEW data rows in Table A, while removing all my past data in `Table A`.
   This is not my desire. **Is there a safe way to do this?**
2. (update rows):
   What if I would like to **UPDATE** data in `Table A`. Using AWS Wrangler, **How can I achieve this, without adding *redundant* rows in `Table A`?**

I have tested (2), using `mode=append` and indeed I ended up getting redundant rows in my `Table A`.

I appreciate if you kindly share your thoughts

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below API:

```
awswrangler.s3.merge_upsert_table
```

Ref: https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.merge_upsert_table.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use `mode="overwrite_partitions"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).